# Python evaluate a string in a based on character criteria

Tags: python

1. I want to take a list of strings and run them thru a loop
2. IF
   string meets criteria1(has_symbol,has_number,has_letter)  OR
   criteria(has_letter,has_number)
3. Add to new list
4. Count iterations i += 1

Thus:
returns a list of ONLY those strings that meet criteria and gives a count of how many are in the list

Tried:

```
for word in list:
    match = re.findall('\w+\d+\W+'), word)
    lst.append(word)
    count += 1
```

Comment: How does your current code fail? Also what do you define as a symbol?

Comment: What else a string can contain? Any particular order in your specifications?

Comment: Im looking to do all possible orders. I know thats a tall order for findall() but its pretty powerful... at the sacrifice of being slowww

Comment: every symbol on the keyboard, paul :)

Answer (score 0):

Any chance it's failing because

```
match = re.findall('\w+\d+\W+'), word)
```

should be

```
match = re.findall('\w+\d+\W+', word)
```

If you only want to add the words that matched you should probably look at match after you check. Also make sure your regex is what you expect. I'd use [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/) for testing that.

```
for word in list:
    match = re.findall('\w+\d+\W+', word)
    if len(match) > 0:
        lst.append(word)
        count += 1
```

Comment: You probably want an if statement after the match = re.findall(etc...) to make sure that re.findall returned any matches. If that's the loop you're using right now it'll add every word from list to lst.

Comment: My problem is that I want to return the whole word that has the criteria and not just the parts of the word that have the criteria

Comment: This should be doing that. The code is adding word to the new list,  not the matches. The matches are only used for checking that you had a match.

Comment: ok yeah that def worked. my only problem now is that i need to either find a way to re.findall() criteria in no certain order or just add all possible critera and possibly use pipe to say either this or that?

Answer (score 0):

import re
count = 0

my_list= ["3This@", "Tad9", "t4443%3g2", "$$Tad##", "#$@^^&*444", "dff$%fggg", "Tad#", "!#$33kk", "Tad4"]

## my_list = [44, 33, 55, 66]

lst= []

for word in my_list:

```
##########CODE HERE##################

match = re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z]+\d+\W+', word)
for m in match:
    if m.istitle():


##########CODE HERE###################
        count += 1
```

print lst
print count

Comment: this is what im trying